# ¿Cómo añadir espacios blancos en css flex?

Tags: html, css

Hola buenas tardes y noches, me gustaría la ayuda del alguno ya que no encuentro solución a este "problema", lo que quiero es hacer cada "px" hacer un espacio en blanco, mediante la propiedad **flex** de **css**, pondré una imagen para que puedan ver como es mi idea ;). Muchas gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funcionamos aquí y para recibir la mejor ayuda posible. En tu pregunta nos debes decir que has intentado, que no te ha funcionado, que errores te ha dado, para que podamos considerarla una pregunta válida. Si no lo haces representa que **no has hecho nada** y puedes recibir [votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874) por ello, y tu pregunta puede quedar [cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) pronto. Gracias por colaborar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola la propiedad flex CSS es realmente super poderosa dependiendo de como la utilices y de las necesidades que tengas. En mi ejemplo para los items no utilizo valores absolutos para asignarles un tamaño concreto. Lo hago respecto al campo visual que ocupa el contenedor de los mismos. Prueba el código en un navegador y veras como se comporta. Con el inspector de código puedes jugar con muchos valores.

```css
.contenedor {
                display: flex;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
                background: #000;
                flex-direction: column;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-around;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .item {
                display: flex;
                background: #dadada;
                width: 30vh;
                height: 30vw;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
            <div class="item">ITEM 1</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 2</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 3</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 4</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 5</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 6</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Si bien es un muy buen aporte, evita responder a preguntas pobremente planteadas, en donde el OP (autor de la pregunta) no haya demostrado lo que ha intentado hasta el momento. Lee [answer].